# Rails: Disable automatic etag header for specific action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible to disable automatic etag header generation in rails for a specific action?

I tried to set response.etag = nil in the action, in an after_filter and in a before_filter. None of them have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E-tags are generated by Rack middleware.  You should be able to skip e-tag generation by setting a cache control header in the response.

This can be done by calling [`expires_now`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ConditionalGet.html#method-i-expires_now) in your controller action to skip caching in Rack and any other servers that handle your request.

[Here is a reference](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-caching-ruby-rails#non-cacheable-content) from Heroku that is applicable to Rails apps in general.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed.